# Bootstrap radio group - horizontal alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've this Bootstrap markup with a inline radio group:

```
<div class="container">
    <section id="content">

        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="myForm">
            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                            <label for="myField" class="control-label">Radio title:</label>

                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="myField" value="normal" /> RADIO1
                            </label>

                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="myField" value="high" /> RADIO2
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </section>
</div>
```

It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I make the title and radio input align horizontally?

See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dennismadsen/u6qus4ud/1/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:middle;` Or `vertical-align:top;` in label.

```
label {
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6qus4ud/2/).

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this, you will need to use the `vertical-align` property.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `.form-group .radio-inline { vertical-align: top; }` to them

Answer (score -1):

In label tag change the radio-inline class to radio class.

```
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="myField" value="normal" /> RADIO1
 </label>
<label class="radio">
`enter code here`<input type="radio" name="myField" value="high" /> RADIO2
                            </label>
```

Comment: Then the elements are not inline.